# detect which part of image is clicked

Tags: android, image

I want to make an app in which I ll show a human body. when we click on any body part the organ name should be displayed with a toast. How will I detect which body part is selected. According to me i ll make small images for every organ. and place those images behind the main image. Is it the right way? How will I draw organs(Bitmaps or png images?).

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way to do it is to draw shapes or even buttons **over** your image, and define them as transparent so you don't see them. Then, using `onClickListener` you can capture what button is clicked and do whatever you want.

Check [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/) for an example

Comment: thanks gilonm. but how will I draw the shapes of organs and place them on original image.

Comment: It is a problem to be very exact with buttons. Shapes could be a better solution. See the link to a tutorial in my edited answer

Comment: I have already referred this example. But I want to draw organs shapes. these are squares. Human body is little complex.

Comment: True, I understand, but I think it is a little too complex to do as far as I know...

Comment: Like I have said, as far as I know - there is no other solution.